# Counting number of unique sentences allowing for mismatches

Tags: python, awk

I have a text file with 200 million sentences. I would like to count the number of occurences of a particular type of sentence in the file and allow for two mismatches in character (this could be insertion of repetitive characters, or two missing characters). The characters are always going to be A, G, C, or T. The position of the mismatched character could be random. I have provided a small sample to illustrate what I am explaining:

I have the following sentences:

```
GTCGAGGTTCTCATCGCCTGGCCGCGCGTGTCTAGATCGGAAGAGCTCGT
GTTTAGGTTCTCATCGCCTGGCCGCGCGTGTCTAGATCGGAAGAGCTCGT
GTCGAGGTTCTCATCGCCTGGCCGCGCGTGTCTAGATCGGAAGAGCTAAT
TAACGTTCAGTTACGGCGTTGAGGTTTTACCTAAGATCGGAAGAGCTCGT
TCCGTAGCGCTCTGCTTCCAGTCGTGGCGGGGAGATCGGAAGAGCTCGTA
TACAAGACTTCATGAATAACGTGACTACGGAGATCGGAAGAGCTCGTATG
TAATGCCACTCCTCTCCCGACTGTTAACACTACTGGTTATATTGACCATG
CGACCTGGGTCAGCTCTGGAGTTTCGTTGAGTTAGATCGGAAGAGCTCGT
ATTTTGATAGTTTGACGGTTAATGCTGGTAATGGTGGTTTTCTTCATTGC
ACCCATGCCTACAGTATTGTTATCGGTAGCAAGCACATCACCTTGAATGC
GCAAGTTGCCATACAAAACAGGGTCGCCAGCAATATCGGTATAAGTCAAA
GAGTTCTAGTGTACGAGAGAGAGACGACGATGGAGATCGGAAGCGCTCTT
TGTTACTACAGGCATAATACGTGTTCCCGGATGAAGATCGGAAGAGCTCG
GACGACCAAAATTAGGGTCAACGCTACCTGTAGGAAGTGTCCGCATAAAG
```

For example if this is the first sentence am looking at

```
 GTCGAGGTTCTCATCGCCTGGCCGCGCGTGTCTAGATCGGAAGAGCTCGT
```

Then the second sentence in the file

```
 GT**TT**AGGTTCTCATCGCCTGGCCGCGCGTGTCTAGATCGGAAGAGCTCGT
```

will be similar to the first sentence because there is just 2 character difference.

Then the third sentence in the file

```
GTCGAGGTTCTCATCGCCTGGCCGCGCGTGTCTAGATCGGAAGAGCT**AA**T
```

here, the last but two characters are modified but everything else is similar to first sentence.

So the unaltered sentence could be anything and then the rest of the sentences are compared to that for two mismatches and then counted. The difference could either be repetitive characters or missing characters, or new characters. And, in the end when you read the file the output will be that a particular sentence occurs 3 times allowing for mismatches.

```
GTCGAGGTTCTCATCGCCTGGCCGCGCGTGTCTAGATCGGAAGAGCTCGT 3 times
```

Is there a way I could use awk? I tried:

```
cat myfile.fq | 
awk '((NR-2)%4==0){character=$1;total++;count[character]++}END{for(character 
   in count){if(!max||count[character]>max) 
    {max=count[character];maxcharacter=character};if(count[character]==1){unique++}};print  total,unique}'
```

---

Edit by Ed Morton - running the above awk script through a C beautifier (https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier) to make it readable produces:

```
((NR - 2) % 4 == 0) {
  character = $1;
  total++;
  count[character]++
}
END {
  for (character in count) {
    if (!max || count[character] > max) {
      max = count[character];
      maxcharacter = character
    };
    if (count[character] == 1) {
      unique++
    }
  };
  print total, unique
}
```

Comment: not fully clear, could you please post more details of this in your post?

Comment: [edit] your question to clarify your requirements. You said a match `could be .. two missing characters` but then you said that `APPLEISEALTHY` is a match for `APPLEISHEALTHY` when they only differ by 1 character. Did you mean "**up to** two"? You said that line 7, `APPLEISHEALT**AA**`, is a match but line 8 which contains exactly the same string is not a match. Are those `**`s REALLY present in your file or did you add them hoping to provide highlighting in the example? If the latter then please remove them so what you provided can be copy/pasted for testing without editing first.

Comment: If everything is based on 2 chars, a case idk how you'll resolve is when 2 chars are removed and 2 new chars are added but they're the same char as one of the 2 chars that were removed. e.g. `FOOBAR` - remove `BA` to get `FOOR` and then add `BB` after the 2 Os to get `FOOBBR`. It LOOKS like there's only 1 char replaced (A->B), so how can you tell if that's a 2-out-and-2-in match or a 1-out-and-1-in non-match?

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements aren't clear but here's a start at what I think you might be trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    tgtStr  = "APPLEISHEALTHY"
    tgtLgth = length(tgtStr)
}
{
    curStr  = $0
    curLgth = length(curStr)

    isMatch = 0

    if ( curStr == tgtStr ) {
        # curStr is tgtStr
        # "APPLEISHEALTHY" vs "APPLEISHEALTHY"
        isMatch = 1
    }
    else if ( curLgth == (tgtLgth-2) ) {
        # curStr may be tgtStr minus 2 chars, e.g.
        # "APPLEISHEALTHY" vs "APPLEISHEALT"
        isMatch = 1
        maxLgth = tgtLgth
        curPos = tgtPos = 0
        for (pos=1; pos<=maxLgth; pos++) {
            curChar = substr(curStr,++curPos,1)
            tgtChar = substr(tgtStr,++tgtPos,1)
            if (curChar != tgtChar) {
                if (curPos == tgtPos) {
                    # first char mismatch but curStr is 2 chars shorter
                    # than tgtStr so thats expected so advance tgtPos
                    # 1 char and back up curPos 1 char and continue.
                    curPos--
                    tgtPos++
                }
                else {
                    # still mismatching after first 2-char skip so fail
                    isMatch = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if ( curLgth == tgtLgth ) {
        # curStr may be tgtStr minus 2 chars plus 2 other chars, e.g.
        # "APPLEISHEALTHY" vs "APPLEISHEALTXX"
    }
    else if ( curLgth == (tgtLgth+2) ) {
        # curStr may be tgtStr plus 2 chars, e.g.
        # "APPLEISHEALTHY" vs "APPLEISHEALTHYXX"
    }

    print curStr, (isMatch ? "is" : "is not"), "a match for", tgtStr
}
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
APPLEISHEALTHY
APPLEISALTHY
APPLEISXLTHY

$ awk -f tst.awk file
APPLEISHEALTHY is a match for APPLEISHEALTHY
APPLEISALTHY is a match for APPLEISHEALTHY
APPLEISXLTHY is not a match for APPLEISHEALTHY
```

You'll have to think through the above logic to see if it's correct and write the logic for the remaining 2 cases but hopefully this shows you how to approach the problem.

Comment: I will edit the post to add a reasonable example instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to have are 'next gen short reads' from a sequencing machine
much as I love ravaging bioinformatics problems with awk for fun and profit.
with indels (insertion/deletion) this is pretty in firmly in the use the right tool for the job which is [local alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith-Waterman_algorithm) typically using [ncbi blast](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi) if you want tried  and true reproducible by everyone results.
(unless this is homework)

Installing blast and figuring out the parameters to accomplish your goal is something you should do any way if you are working in this space.